# Unwrap optionals in for statement

Tags: swift

I have an [UIImageView?] array and want to iterate over all of the non-nil values. Here are the things I've tried:

```
    // Kind of work:
for imageView in imageViews where imageView != nil { // works, but still have to use imageView! rather than imageView
for tmp in imageViews { guard let imageView = tmp else { continue } // works but feels wrong, looks weird/confusing, and neems unnecessarily longwinded

    // Don't work: (in no particular order)
for x in imageViews, let imageView = x {
for let imageView in imageViews {
for (imageView in imageViews) as? UIImageView {
for imageView in imageViews as? UIImageView {
for imageView? in imageViews {
for imageView in imageViews ?? false {
for imageView in? imageViews {
for x in imageViews where let imageView = x {
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for case let .Some(x) in imageViews {
   ...
}
```

or even without a loop:

```
let result = imageViews.flatMap { x in ... }
```

You can even use a normal loop over the flatMap result:

```
for imageView in imageViews.flatMap({$0}) {

}
```

Comment: I would like the `for case let imageView in imageViews {` but it doesn't work as I'd expect. I get the error `Value of optional type 'Optional<UIImageViews>' not unwrapped` Just as I do regularly.

Comment: @EricD. `for imageView in imageViews.flatMap({$0}) { ... } `

Comment: `let imageView = imageViews.flatMap { x in ... }` causes `Cannot invoke 'flatMap' with an argument list of type '((UIImageView?) throws -> _)'`
trying your comment now.

Comment: @EricD. you probably were having problems not adding the parentheses  around the closure ;)

Comment: It's definitely a [UIImageView?]

`let imageViews: [UIImageView?] = [nil, UIImageView(), nil, UIImageView()]
let result = imageViews.flatMap { x in // Cannot invoke 'flatMap' with an argument list of type '((UIImageView?) throws -> _)`

`let imageViews: [UIImageView?] = [nil, UIImageView(), nil, UIImageView()]
for case let imageView in imageViews {
imageView.layer // Value of optional type 'Optional<UIImageView>' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?}`

Comment: The "for case let" you're using is wrong, look at my updated answer. It's `for case let .Some(x) `. The flatMap command also works, I've tested (and Matt answered a bit later with the same idea).

Comment: Thank's for this! As you say both your first and last examples work. I tried to look up .Some() with no luck. Apparently the word "some" is used too much. And Xcode doesn't show a reference to it in the quick help. Where can I find a description of what that is.

Comment: You're welcome. This ".Some()" comes from Optionals. An Optional actually has either .Some(value) or .None - have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330 :)

Comment: Nice use of `for case let` construct.

Comment: Here is a link to the .Some() Pattern description https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-ID520

Eric D. your link seemed close, but didn't actually talk about this at all. Fortunately you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks again.

Comment: Note you could make this slightly cleaner by using the optional pattern, i.e `for case let x? in imageViews  {...}` :)

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `flatMap`, which eliminates nils and unwraps the remaining Optionals. Simple test example:

```
let arr : [UIImageView?] = [nil, UIImageView(), nil, UIImageView()]
let arr2 = arr.flatMap{$0} // eliminates the nils, unwraps the optionals
for iv in arr2 {
    ...
}
```

On that basis, what I would *actually* write:

```
let arr : [UIImageView?] = [nil, UIImageView(), nil, UIImageView()]
arr.flatMap{$0}.forEach {iv in
    print(iv) // or whatever
}
```

You will find `forEach` to be very often preferable to `for...in`, and this sort of chained situation is a good case in point.

Comment: Thanks for this. Both your examples work as advertised, and I may get some use out of the second form if it; but I can only mark one answer as correct of course. Up voted though.

Comment: `flatMap` is a very strange and (in my view) poorly constructed API, because it actually does (at least) two very different things: it flattens array-of-array, and it safely unwraps array-of-Optionals. However, it does do the latter, so I just wanted to make the point that it is what you should think of when that's the task at hand. Eric's use of `for case let` is delightful, though, and I think you're right to accept his very complete answer.