# Iterate NSSet and cast to type in one step

Tags: swift

Is there a way to cast elements from a NSSet (or any non-native Swift collection) and cast each element to a type in one step. Currently I'm doing this

```
// "zoo" is an NSOrderedSet
for animal in zoo {
  if let animal = animal as? Animal {
    if animal.needFeeding {
      // Feed the animal
    }
  }
}
```

the above seems a bit clumsy. The set is coming from CoreData so I have to use NSSet.

Comment: If the set is coming from Core Data it's supposed to have an unique type so the type check might be dispensable.

Comment: @vadian: That is indeed a good point!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use pattern matching `case let` in a `for` loop:

```
for case let animal as Animal in zoo  {
    if animal.needFeeding {

    }
}
```

Note that this will just skip elements which are not instances of
(a subclass of)  `Animal`.

Comment: Why not even `for case let animal as Animal in zoo where animal.needFeeding {...` ? ;-)

Comment: @vadian: Sure! I just wanted to answer the question "how to iterate and cast in one step". Also more statements might be added to the loop later. (Actually I am not sure which version I would prefer for legibility.)

Answer (score 6):

Just for completeness, `NSOrderedSet` is just a combination of a set and an array, you could use either one of them for iterating, casting it to the Swift `Set` or `Array` type:

```
for animal in zoo.set as! Set<Animal> {
    if animal.needFeeding {
    }
}
```

or

```
for animal in zoo.array as! [Animal] {
    if animal.needFeeding {
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution can work, but the case option is the best since it's possible for a set to contain other items than an Animal.

Answer (score 2):

For NSOrderedSet and the like, I would safely loop over mapped content like this:

```
for animal in zoo.flatMap({ $0 as? Animal }) {
    if animal.needFeeding {
        // Feed the animal
    }
}
```

*Ah, of course, there's a similar Q&A... and I already answered something similar. More alternatives in the other one, though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35558210/2227743*